# loop for a table-valued function in Oracle sql

Tags: oracle, function

I have a `table-valued` function `f_customer_return_rate` (that returns a table, not a number)

```
Customer_id      end_date       period    RATE
1234             '2020-12-31'   12        0.3
```

and i want to run it many times to get return rate for many customers. How do i loop it, or embed it in a query?

Eg i want

```
select customer_id,

        select RATE
        from table(f_customer_return_rate (    
                                customer_id, -- customer id
                                To_date('2020-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), --end_date IN DATE,
                                12 -- period: since how many months ago
                        )
        )
        where rownum = 1
        
        as return_rate
        
FROM customer_table -- this table has 1000 customers
```

It throws err

> [Code: 936, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00936: missing expression

Is it because this function is table-valued and can't be put into a column?

Any way i can loop (ideally embed in a query) and put the results for 1000 customers together?

Comment: can you desc the `f_customer_return_rate` table? is there a customer_id in it?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd do it this way.  I'd prefer a temporary table, and a simple loop in a function to populate it based on the query, so that I could query the static temporary table afterwards

Comment: @jad returned table has other columns - all columns I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not happening from the function you are calling.
You are missing a couple of parenthesis.

```
select customer_id,

        --> here
        (select RATE
        from table(f_customer_return_rate (    
                                customer_id, -- customer id
                                To_date('2020-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), --end_date IN DATE,
                                12 -- period: since how many months ago
                        )
        )
        where rownum = 1) --> here
        as return_rate
        
FROM customer_table -- this table has 1000 customers
```